# How to create a rectangle shape with 2 sides in android

Tags: android

I want to show edit text box with two sides. so, for that i need to create a rectangle shape with two sides. PLease help some one.

Comment: ? A rectangle has 4 sides.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what your question means. A little clarity please. Can you elaborate. From simple geometry I can tell you, you can't build a rectangle with 2 side

Answer (score 3):

create a drawable under drawable folder and add the belwow contents (border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="@color/black" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Now set the Background of the EditText to this draw able like :

```
 android:background="@drawable/border"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to create a 9-patch in PhotoShop with required border sides... there are also several other ways... depends on your design.